# batch using filename in variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

I was thinking it will be easy but become headache
I'm trying to set a variable contains filename like;

```
SET %~n1_var=(%~z1)
or
SET /a %~n1_var=(%~z1)
```

But when it comes to call back, even I couldn't test is it set or not like;

```
ECHO %%~n1_var%
or
ECHO "%~n1_var%"
```

Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found. Magic command is "ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION"

Comment: Don't forget the `setlocal` in front of it!

Comment: Thank you, sure already did. And realized one detail maybe helps other searchnig same;  A variable name like [%~n1_percent] doesn't work with file names starting with a number ??? But when you change it to [percent_%~n1] it works.  All bests